# Append div to another div (CoffeeScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, coffeescript

I have div with error

```
  <div data-role="dialog" id="step_2_ajax_error">
  <div data-role="header" data-id="persistent" data-position="fixed">
    <div class="mini_logo"><a href="/" data-ajax="false"><%= image_tag "#{image_folder}/logo.png", fetch_format: :auto %></a></div>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="background-color: #ececec;">
    <%= _('Tyvärr bekräftades inte era platser. Gör vänligen en ny sökning.') %>
    <br/>
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a"><%= _('Stäng') %></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to load it to another div via coffeescript

Here is it

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="step_2_error" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-b">
  <div data-role="header" data-id="persistent" data-position="fixed">
    <div class="mini_logo"><a href="/" data-ajax="false"><%= image_tag "#{image_folder}/logo.png", fetch_format: :auto %></a></div>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="step_2_error_content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is how I try to do it

```
showAjaxErrorScreen = () ->
$('#step_2_error_content').load("#step_2_ajax_error")
$.mobile.changePage '#step_2_error', changeHash: false
log_event "Show ajax error screen"
Honeybadger.notify raiseError('Ajax not OK on step_2', 'NOT OK')
```

But it just open blank screen. And not loading error div.

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was find answer.

I was able to run it like

```
$.mobile.changePage '#step_2_ajax_error', changeHash: false
```